SSRS export report as JSON
We are using SQL Server Management studio to develop a stored procedure that outputs data to JSON via "FOR JSON PATH"
The issue we have is trying to use SSRS to utilize this SPROC and have the data exported as a .json file.
Any way to do this via SSRS?
Currently we are trying table or textbox to display the data, but output gets truncated and doesn't keep formatting/special characters for a valid json file.
Currently we are trying table or textbox to display the data, but output gets truncated and doesn't keep formatting/special characters for a valid json file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

SSRS does not support exporting data in JSON format out of the box. SSRS either renders reports on the screen or it can export data using these format options.
SSRS Report Viewer and Export Options
These options can be expanded, but that requires implementing a rendering extension for your SSRS Server and making modifications to the server's configuration files. I am currently not aware of how to implement that and I am not able to find any examples of someone sharing how they implemented this.
I think the closest you could get without making changes to the server or writing a custom rendering extension, and that may be worth trying, is "stuffing" all of your json data into one field in your stored procedure and then adding that one field to your SSRS report with nothing else in the report. You can then export it as a CSV, basically a text document. However, there may be some truncating issues still and it will force you to save the file with a .csv file extension.
